# Regex expression for parsing SQL Server schema and tablename

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse schema and table name using a regular expression. I am using C# (.NET Core) and `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Here are examples how the input can look like:

```
Schema.TableName
Schema . TableName
[Schema].[TableName]
[Schema] . [TableName]
Schema. [TableName]
[SchemaPart1.Part2.Part  3].[Table . Name]
```

And of course other variations that SQL Server accepts when you want to create a table using table and schema name.

Also, I am supporting other databases (MySql & Postgres), so I will reuse the same regex, but replace the [] with the right quotation character (` or " ). But I used the Sql Server examples because the start and ending quotation character are different.

My current regular expression looks like this:

```
\.?\[.+?\]|[^\[]+?(?=\.)|[^\[]+
```

This does work most of the times. But e.g. in this case `[Schema] . [TableName]` I get a match for whitespaces in between which I am not quite sure how to filter out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regular expression might not be the best toll here. Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1) is helpful. Especially the `ParseSchemaObjectName()` method seems to do what you want.

Comment: If you absolutely want to do this with an expression, I would suggest matching the parts you expect in sequence: schema, period with optional space, table; that also makes it possible to capture, if necessary. For example: `^(?:\[[^]]+]|\w+) *\. *(?:\[[^]]+]|\w+)`.

Comment: @stickybit : Thanks for replay. This is actually a good hint. But I am planning to reuse the same regex to parse the table names for other databases, e.g. "public"."table1" for Postgres DBs. TSqlTParser would only work for Sql Server.

Comment: @oriberu I tried to get your expression work with regex tester (http://regexstorm.net/tester), but the expression didn't work there as expected. What did I wrong?

Comment: @Andreas Be sure to check `Multiline` to the right before running the regex. regex101.com doesn't support .NET-style syntax per se, but it's so close to PCRE that it might be worth using that site for most of the cases; I find it easier to use for tweaking, since you see live results: https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/1.

Comment: @oriberu Thanks for the link to regex101 com. I see that it provides a better support for creating regex expression. But the result of your expression is not what I actually look for - it will match the whole line, but I am interested in schema and tablename. Using my own regex with regex101 I get a result that works for some - only if there is whitespace around the "." (like `[schema] . [tablename]`) the regex doesn't work. https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/2

Comment: @Andreas You could just make the non-capturing groups into capturing groups in my expression, see this updated demo: https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/3 - wouldn't that work? The advantage of this approach is, that you'll get related schema and table names grouped together.

Comment: @Andreas As for your expression, presuming you want to match leading period and space for the table (?), here is an update: https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/4 - the ` *` accounts for spaces between period and table.

Comment: Hi @oriberu , changing the non-capturing groups into capturing groups should have been something I should have thought of myself. Thanks for pointing this out. I just looked at both expressions, and they look very good! #3 was the one I was hoping for, but I like the last one because it is so much shorter. If you want you can post both expressions as answer to the question, I will flag them  as the "accepted answer". Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to match schema, table and delimiters at once and use capturing groups to get the names separated from surrounding fluff. For example:

```regex
`/^(\[[^]]+]|\w+) *\. *(\[[^]]+]|\w+)/gm`
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/3).

C# example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...
String text = "Schema.TableName\nSchema . TableName\n[Schema].[TableName]\n[Schema] . [TableName]\nSchema. [TableName]\n[SchemaPart1.Part2.Part  3].[Table . Name]";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^(\[[^]]+\]|\w+) *\. *(\[[^]]+\]|\w+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match match = re.Match(text);

while (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("( '{0}', '{1}' )", match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
'Schema', 'TableName'
'Schema', 'TableName'
'[Schema]', '[TableName]'
'[Schema]', '[TableName]'
'Schema', '[TableName]'
'[SchemaPart1.Part2.Part  3]', '[Table . Name]'
```

**OR**

If you want to match schema or table without differentiating between them, you could try a variation of your expression. Be advised that this would also match simple strings like `foo`. For example:

```regex
`/\.? *(?:\[[^]]+\]|\w+)/g`
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h793L7/4).

C# example (`using` and `text` same as above):

```cs
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\.? *(?:\[[^]]+\]|\w+)");
foreach (Match m in matches) Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", m);
```

Output:

```
'Schema'
'.TableName'
'Schema'
'. TableName'
'[Schema]'
'.[TableName]'
'[Schema]'
'. [TableName]'
'Schema'
'. [TableName]'
'[SchemaPart1.Part2.Part  3]'
'.[Table . Name]'
```

Comment: Thanks again for your effort! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

or with labelling the parts , and removing the brackets

```
(?:(?:\[(?<server>[^\]]*)\]|(?<server>[^\.]*))\.)?(?:(?:\[(?<catalog>[^\]]*)\]|(?<catalog>[^\.]*))\.)?(?:(?:\[(?<schema>[^\]]*)\]|(?<schema>[^\.]*))\.)?(?:\[(?<object>[^\]]*)\]|(?<object>[^\.]*))$
```

!this needs righttoleft parsing

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
"(?:(?:\\[(?<server>[^\\]]*)\\]|(?<server>[^\\.]*))\\.)?(?:(?" +
":\\[(?<catalog>[^\\]]*)\\]|(?<catalog>[^\\.]*))\\.)?(?:(?:\\[" +
"(?<schema>[^\\]]*)\\]|(?<schema>[^\\.]*))\\.)?(?:\\[(?<objec" +
"t>[^\\]]*)\\]|(?<object>[^\\.]*))$",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline 
| RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled
| RegexOptions.RightToLeft );
```